# MySQL: searching children records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Assume 2 tables:

```
TABLE: team
-----------
| team_id |
===========
| 1       |
-----------
| 2       |
-----------

TABLE: team_member
-------------------------------------------
| team_member_id | team_id | age | gender |
===========================================
| 1              | 1       | 20  | Male   |
-------------------------------------------
| 1              | 2       | 25  | Male   |
-------------------------------------------
| 1              | 2       | 23  | Female |
-------------------------------------------
```

How do I search for things like this:

1. List of all teams that are only male, between ages of 18 and 25.
2. List of all teams that are male and female, where either gender is between ages of 18 and 25.
3. Etc.

I'm basically looking for general strategies on how to apply certain filters (e.g. age) across all the children records of `team`. Suggestions?

Comment: General strategy: `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Comment: @RayToal, GROUP BY the `team_id`, right? How does HAVING help? For example, how do I find a team that has 3 members, all male? Or find teams where all the members are under 25? The problem I have is how to apply a certain condition to some or all of the children profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

team, team_member

You can't just apply a simple WHERE clause if you are checking for only an all male or all female team... it needs to be compared against the full set of team members.  Try

```
select 
      tm.team_id,
      sum( if( tm.gender = 'Male' AND tm.age between 18 and 25, 1, 0 )) as MaleInRange,
      count(*) AllTeamMembers
  from
      team_member tm
  group by
      tm.Team_ID
  having
      MaleInRange = AllTeamMembers
```

Similarly, to ensure you have BOTH male AND female...

```
select 
      tm.team_id,
      sum( if( tm.age between 18 and 25, 1, 0 )) as AgeInRange,
      sum( if( tm.gender = 'Male', 1, 0 )) as MaleCnt,
      sum( if( tm.gender = 'Female', 1, 0 )) as FemaleCnt,
      count(*) AllTeamMembers
  from
      team_member tm
  group by
      tm.Team_ID
  having
         AgeInRange = AllTeamMembers
     AND MaleCnt > 0
     AND FemaleCnt > 0
```

Comment: I think I understand the solution. Will try it out tomorrow. By the way, I'm not only interested in gender and age. I only used those to simplify my problem. I have about 10-15 fields. Will this scale?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie, the number of columns, I too don't care about... just the gender and age.  Just make sure you have an index on team_member by the team_id.  As for ability to scale with large data, it should be no problem... unless you have like a million teams.  Then, I would adjust the team table with roll-up values, such as #men, #women, low age, high age, then you could query from  that (with appropriate indexes)

Comment: When you "roll up" values, do you mean to actually create fields in the parent table to contain these "computed" values. If so, does that become unnormalized?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie, yes, it would become de-normalized, but you could have a trigger whenever adding / editing a teammate to update the counts to the new columns at the team level.  However, how large are these Team and Team_Mate tables going to get.  Having "roll-up" columns are common, think of a business doing sales of a product, they keep track of how many sold, total sales value, total cost of those goods sold so the bean-counters can see sales activity and be happy with numbers.  They don't want to requery every second, every record.

Answer (score 0):

Something like - 
SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE key_col > 1
  AND key_col < 10;

Check this example - http://www.roseindia.net/sql/mysql-example/mysql-range.shtml. Hope it helps!

Comment: This wasn't an attempt to query for a range. Rather, it's a question on how to query children records as a "whole". For example, how to query teams that are comprised of a male and female member?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:
 1. `SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE Gender='Male' and Age BETWEEN 18 AND 25`.
 2. `SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE Age BETWEEN 18 AND 25`.
Hope it helps!

Comment: This does not address the actual concern of the problem. The concern is how to query children records as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

BTW **team_member_id must be unique or this column is useless !!**

List of all teams that are male and female, where either gender is between ages of 18 and 25.

```
SELECT * FROM team_member WHERE Age BETWEEN 18 AND 25 GROUP BY team_id.
```

result

```
| team_member_id | team_id | age | gender |
===========================================
| 1              | 1       | 20  | Male   |
-------------------------------------------
| 1              | 2       | 25  | Male   |
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you want to get teams that comprise of a male and female, between 18 and 25 years old, `team_member_id` = 1 should ***not*** be in the result.